# Perl RegEx Remove Double Characters Not Double Numbers in a String

Tags: regex, perl

I am using Perl RegExp that attempts to remove BOTH double characters and double numbers.
However, I only want to remove double characters and leave double numbers present in the same string.

Although there are several examples showing removing double characters, there are no examples showing removing double characters and keeping double numbers in a string.

My Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use v5.10.0;
use warnings;

my $double = "AAPPLES112233";
$double =~ s/(.)\1/$1/gi;
say $double;
```

My code outputs APLES123.  However the goal is to output APLES112233, eliminating the double characters while keeping the double numbers in the same string.

Comment: @revo The answer in the reference you give is wrong in Perl as it's only a match operator. Trivial to adjust but perhaps not for those who need this question.

Comment: @zdim OP just need to copy the regex into the corresponding pattern space. Questions aren't supposed to be exact duplicates and this one is asked many times before. If you have a better dupe please tell me. I'll add.

Comment: @revo Yes and yes; these comments take care of what was itching (me).  Just a mention, for people who are new to regex (and across different tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.`, which matches *nearly any character* (letters and numbers included), use `[a-z]` instead, which will match only alphabetical characters:

```
$double =~ s/([a-z])\1/$1/gi;
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks @CertainPerformance.

Comment: `A-z` contains six more characters that may not be needed.

Comment: This will also include  other characters like `_` which is considered in the range [A-z]. since you are ignoring the case ie using `i` why just not use `A-Z`??